Quick Semicolon Usage Question
I'll keep it quick and to the point.
I'm aware semi-colons are used to join two related independent clauses but would it apply in this instance?
"After all this time; always."
For context, this is taken from a quote from Harry Potter where one character is questioning another's continued love for someone long after their passing so they ask, "After all this time?" and he replied "Always." I'm trying to rephrase it as a statement rather than a question and answer to title a photo album to my partner for our anniversary.
Thanks in advance!

He said after all this time, always. OR He said after all this time: always. But this is editing so not really allowed here.

Has your partner passed? If not ... you can do better than this.

After all this time: Always.

Can you give context, e.g. the previous line? How do you intend this to be used?
